# Service discovery with eureka is not working in docker container

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, microservices, ocelot, steeltoe

When I run my API gateway in docker container then it is not able to find my services which are registered in eureka.

**API Gateway**

-- ocelot.json

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/values",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "UseServiceDiscovery": true,
      "ServiceName": "sampleservice",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/sample-api/{catchAll}"
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "UseServiceDiscovery": true,
    "ServiceDiscoveryProvider": {
      "Type": "Eureka",
      "Host": "myeurekaserver",
      "Port": "8761"
    }
  }
}
```

**--** appsettings.json  for API Gateway

```
{
  "eureka": {
    "client": {
      "shouldRegisterWithEureka": false,
      "serviceUrl": "http://myeurekaserver:8761/eureka/",
      "ValidateCertificates": false
    },
    "instance": { 
      "appName": "gateway",
      "hostName": "myeurekaserver", 
      "port": "7000"
    }
  }
}
```

**Service Configuration --appsettings.json**

```
{
  "eureka": {
    "client": {
      "shouldRegisterWithEureka": true,
      "serviceUrl": "http://myeurekaserver:8761/eureka/",
      "ValidateCertificates": false
    },
    "instance": {
      "appName": "sampleservice",
      "hostName": "myeurekaserver",
      "port": "7001"
    }
  }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sampleapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}sampleapi
    ports:
      - "7001:80"
    networks:
      - ecnetwork
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SampleAPI/Dockerfile

  gateway:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}gateway
    ports:
      - "7000:80"
    networks:
      - ecnetwork
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Gateway/Dockerfile


  myeurekaserver:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myeurekaserver
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - ecnetwork
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyEurekaServer/Dockerfile

networks:
  ecnetwork:
    external: true
```

When I run command docker-compose up and check on http://localhost:8761/ I find my services have been registred in the eureka server, but I run `http://localhost:7000/sample-api/order`
It returns

> localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

I checked my console window, then It is API gateway is able to discover the services, here is the log.

```
gateway_1     | dbug: Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka.DiscoveryClient[0]
gateway_1     |       FetchRegistryDelta returned: OK
gateway_1     | dbug: Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka.DiscoveryClient[0]
gateway_1     |       FetchRegistry succeeded
```

Comment: Did you try to get into your gateway container and curl myeurekaserver?

Comment: Does your myeurekaserver container name fit your configuration?

Comment: Are there any log entries on the web service to indicate that it has received any traffic?

Answer (score 0):

It's an application error, check your app API gateway.

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable

Try to debug your application without Docker.

Comment: I tried, It is working pefectly fine on local without docker.

Comment: for local I replaced `myeurekaserver` with `localhost` in `appsettings`

Answer (score 0):

Check in the docker on which port the service is registered 7000 or 80?
Then see if the 7000 port is accessible for you in local by telnet